# Como inibir o efeito de aumento da logo no mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

Já agradeço desde já àquele que dispor a me ajudar. Primeiramente eu entendo o básico do básico de html e css, e estou montando uma loja online com um template já pronto, só estou adicionando o que preciso e às vezes dou umas editadas nos códigos.
O menu superior do site possui um efeito em que, ao rolar para baixo, ele se encurta, e os botões e a logo ali presentes, também. O problema está no mobile, acontece que o menu encurta, mas a logo, ao invés de manter o mesmo tamanho, ela aumenta e invade o espaço das outras funções. Abaixo tem a imagem que anexei.
Lembrando que no desktop tudo flui normalmente, o problema é somente esse no mobile.

[image: À esquerda, o tamanho normal, que é o jeito que eu quero que continue ao descer a página. À direita, é como ela fica ao rolar a página devido ao efeito.]

Abaixo há todos os códigos em que a logo está presente:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    //funcoes do menu no mobile
    var htmlMenuSup = $("#menu-sup-minimalist small").html();
    $("#menu-sup-minimalist-mobile").html(htmlMenuSup);
    $(".navbar-toggle-MenuTop").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#aspnetForm").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
    </script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    //Efeito do Menu
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
            $(".top-header").slideUp("fast");
            $("#menu-top-scroll").addClass('scrolled')
        } else {
            $(".top-header").slideDown("fast");
            $("#menu-top-scroll").removeClass('scrolled')
        }
    });

    //Regras gerais do tema
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $("#ctl00_TdDireita").remove();
        $("#ctl00_TdEsquerda").remove();
        $(".menuSuperior ").addClass("navbar-right");
        $(".ul_master_categories ").removeClass("nav-pills");
        $(".ul_master_categories ").removeClass("nav-stacked");
        $(".menuInferior ").removeClass("navbar-nav");
        $(".ul_master_categories ").addClass("navbar-nav");
        $("#ctl00_RowCenter").removeClass("container");
        $("#ctl00_TdBody").removeClass("col-md-8");
        $("#ctl00_TdBody ").addClass("container");
        $(".home #ctl00_TdBody ").removeClass();
        $(".categories #ctl00_TdBody ").removeClass();
        $(".categories #ctl00_TdBody ").addClass("col-md-12");
        $("#ctl00_txt1").attr("placeholder", "Digite o termo para pesquisa...");
        $("#ctl00_txt1").addClass("input-lg");
    });

    //funcoes da busca
    function exibeBusca() {
        $("#form-busca").fadeIn("fast");
    }
    function fecharBusca() {
        $("#form-busca").fadeOut("fast");
    }
    $(document).keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27) { // Esc
            fecharBusca();
        }
    });
</script>
```

```css
.navbar {
      position: relative;
      min-height: 45px;
      margin-bottom: 21px;
      border: 1px solid transparent;
    }
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .navbar {
        border-radius: 0;
      }
    }
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .navbar-header {
        float: left;
      }
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
      overflow-x: visible;
      padding-right: 15px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      border-top: 1px solid transparent;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
              box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
      -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.in {
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .navbar-collapse {
        width: auto;
        border-top: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
                box-shadow: none;
      }
      .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: block !important;
        height: auto !important;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        overflow: visible !important;
      }
      .navbar-collapse.in {
        overflow-y: visible;
      }
      .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse,
      .navbar-static-top .navbar-collapse,
      .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
      }
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse,
    .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
      max-height: 340px;
    }
    @media (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape) {
      .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse,
      .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
        max-height: 200px;
      }
    }
    .container > .navbar-header,
    .container-fluid > .navbar-header,
    .container > .navbar-collapse,
    .container-fluid > .navbar-collapse {
      margin-right: -15px;
      margin-left: -15px;
    }
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .container > .navbar-header,
      .container-fluid > .navbar-header,
      .container > .navbar-collapse,
      .container-fluid > .navbar-collapse {
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
      }
    }
    .navbar-static-top {
      z-index: 1000;
      border-width: 0 0 1px;
    }
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .navbar-static-top {
        border-radius: 0;
      }
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top,
    .navbar-fixed-bottom {
      position: fixed;
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 1030;
    }
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .navbar-fixed-top,
      .navbar-fixed-bottom {
        border-radius: 0;
      }
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top {
      top: 0;
      border-width: 0 0 1px;
    }
    .navbar-fixed-bottom {
      bottom: 0;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      border-width: 1px 0 0;
    }
   .navbar-brand {
        float: left;
        padding:0;
        font-size: 19px;
        line-height: 21px;
        max-width: 200px;
        height: inherit;
    }
    .navbar-brand:hover,
    .navbar-brand:focus {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .navbar-brand > img {
      display: block;
    }
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .navbar > .container .navbar-brand,
      .navbar > .container-fluid .navbar-brand {
        margin-left: -15px;
      }
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
      position: relative;
      float: right;
      margin-right: 15px;
      padding: 9px 10px;
      margin-top: 5.5px;
      margin-bottom: 5.5px;
      background-color: transparent;
      background-image: none;
      border: 1px solid transparent;
      border-radius: 0;
    }
    .navbar-toggle:focus {
      outline: 0;
    }
    .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
      display: block;
      width: 22px;
      height: 2px;
      border-radius: 1px;
    }
    .navbar-toggle .icon-bar + .icon-bar {
      margin-top: 4px;
    }
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .navbar-toggle {
        display: none;
      }
    }
    .navbar-nav {
      margin: 6px -15px;
    }
    .navbar-nav > li > a {
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      line-height: 21px;
    }
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
      .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
        position: static;
        float: none;
        width: auto;
        margin-top: 0;
        background-color: transparent;
        border: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
                box-shadow: none;
      }
      .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a,
      .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
        padding: 5px 15px 5px 25px;
      }
      .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
        line-height: 21px;
      }
      .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
      .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
        background-image: none;
      }
    }
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .navbar-nav {
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .navbar-nav > li {
        float: left;
      }
      .navbar-nav > li > a {
        padding-top: 12px;
        padding-bottom: 12px;
      }
    }
    .navbar-form {
      margin-left: -15px;
      margin-right: -15px;
      padding: 10px 15px;
      border-top: 1px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
      margin-top: 3px;
      margin-bottom: 3px;
    }
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .navbar-form .form-group {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }
      .navbar-form .form-control {
        display: inline-block;
        width: auto;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }
      .navbar-form .form-control-static {
        display: inline-block;
      }
      .navbar-form .input-group {
        display: inline-table;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }
      .navbar-form .input-group .input-group-addon,
      .navbar-form .input-group .input-group-btn,
      .navbar-form .input-group .form-control {
        width: auto;
      }
      .navbar-form .input-group > .form-control {
        width: 100%;
      }
      .navbar-form .control-label {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }
      .navbar-form .radio,
      .navbar-form .checkbox {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }
      .navbar-form .radio label,
      .navbar-form .checkbox label {
        padding-left: 0;
      }
      .navbar-form .radio input[type="radio"],
      .navbar-form .checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
        position: relative;
        margin-left: 0;
      }
      .navbar-form .has-feedback .form-control-feedback {
        top: 0;
      }
    }
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
      .navbar-form .form-group {
        margin-bottom: 5px;
      }
      .navbar-form .form-group:last-child {
        margin-bottom: 0;
      }
    }
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .navbar-form {
        width: auto;
        border: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
      }
    }
    .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
      margin-top: 0;
      border-top-right-radius: 0;
      border-top-left-radius: 0;
    }
    .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      border-top-right-radius: 0;
      border-top-left-radius: 0;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    }
    .navbar-btn {
      margin-top: 3px;
      margin-bottom: 3px;
    }
    .navbar-btn.btn-sm {
      margin-top: 4.5px;
      margin-bottom: 4.5px;
    }
    .navbar-btn.btn-xs {
      margin-top: 11.5px;
      margin-bottom: 11.5px;
    }
    .navbar-text {
      margin-top: 12px;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
    }
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .navbar-text {
        float: left;
        margin-left: 15px;
        margin-right: 15px;
      }
    }
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .navbar-left {
        float: left !important;
      }
      .navbar-right {
        float: right !important;
        margin-right: -15px;
      }
      .navbar-right ~ .navbar-right {
        margin-right: 0;
      }
    }
    .navbar-default {
      background-color: #333333;
      border-color: #222222;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-brand {
      color: #000;
    }
    .navbar-default {
        background-color: #fff;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ececec!important;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-text {
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
        color: #a1c037 !important;
        background-color: transparent !important;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
      color: [CorLinks];
      background-color: [CorPrincipalTema];
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .disabled > a,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .disabled > a:hover,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .disabled > a:focus {
      color: #cccccc;
      background-color: transparent;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
      border-color: transparent;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
    .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
      background-color: transparent;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
      background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
    .navbar-default .navbar-form {
      border-color: #222222;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
      background-color: #272727;
      color: #ffffff;
    }

    @media (max-width: 767px) {
      .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
        color: #ffffff;
      }
      .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
      .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: #272727;
      }
      .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
      .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
      .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: #272727;
      }
      .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a,
      .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:hover,
      .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:focus {
        color: #cccccc;
        background-color: transparent;
      }
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-link {
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    .navbar-default .btn-link {
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    .navbar-default .btn-link:hover,
    .navbar-default .btn-link:focus {
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    .navbar-default .btn-link[disabled]:hover,
    fieldset[disabled] .navbar-default .btn-link:hover,
    .navbar-default .btn-link[disabled]:focus,
    fieldset[disabled] .navbar-default .btn-link:focus {
      color: #cccccc;
    }
    .navbar-inverse {
      background-color: [CorBotaoPrimario];
      border-color: [CorBotaoPrimarioHover];
    }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:hover,
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:focus {
      color: #ffffff;
      background-color: transparent;
    }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-text {
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
      color: #ffffff;
      background-color: [CorBotaoPrimarioHover];
    }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a,
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
      color: #ffffff;
      background-color: [CorBotaoPrimarioHover];
    }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .disabled > a,
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .disabled > a:hover,
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .disabled > a:focus {
      color: #444444;
      background-color: transparent;
    }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle {
      border-color: transparent;
    }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:hover,
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:focus {
      background-color: transparent;
    }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
      background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse,
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-form {
      border-color: #007196;
    }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a,
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
      background-color: [CorBotaoPrimarioHover];
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
      .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-header {
        border-color: [CorBotaoPrimarioHover];
      }
      .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .divider {
        background-color: [CorBotaoPrimarioHover];
      }
      .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
        color: #ffffff;
      }
      .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
      .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: [CorBotaoPrimarioHover];
      }
      .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
      .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
      .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: [CorBotaoPrimarioHover];
      }
      .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a,
      .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:hover,
      .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:focus {
        color: #444444;
        background-color: transparent;
      }
    }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-link {
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-link:hover {
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    .navbar-inverse .btn-link {
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    .navbar-inverse .btn-link:hover,
    .navbar-inverse .btn-link:focus {
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    .navbar-inverse .btn-link[disabled]:hover,
    fieldset[disabled] .navbar-inverse .btn-link:hover,
    .navbar-inverse .btn-link[disabled]:focus,
    fieldset[disabled] .navbar-inverse .btn-link:focus {
      color: #444444;
    }
```

```html
<div class="no-padding" id="menu-top-scroll">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
            <div class="navbar-header m-t-20 m-b-20">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">[logo]</a>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Já tentou colocar um width em % na logo?

Comment: Sim sim, já tentei. Tanto modificando a max-width, quanto colocando uma nova e alterando os valores.

Comment: O site está publicado, vc tem um link?

Comment: Yep. https://grmed.001shop.com.br/
Ele ainda tá em construção.

Answer (score -2):

seria legal você criar um div para a logo desktop e outra para a logo mobile, isso vai manter seu codigo organizado e resolver seu ploblema.

cada um receberá um tamanho, no caso a do desk você mantem o tamanho atual e no mobile, você estiliza para que se encaixe no mobile, com isso a imagem não vazará quando a tela for menor

Comment: Valeu Fernanda! Vou tentar essa alternativa